# Как сделать изменение дизайна item в recyclerView при клике на него?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, viewholder

Есть адаптер и я не понимаю как мне в нем сделать чтобы при клике на элемент он становился с определенным фоном, а при клике на другой элемент соответственно тот новый элемент приобретал новый фон , а старый итем применял дефолтный фон. Подскажите , как можно реализовать такую логику, это логика обычного выбора размера в карточке товара.

```
public class RecyclerViewOfferSizeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewOfferSizeAdapter.SizeViewHolder>{

    public interface OnStateClickListener {
        void onStateClick(OffersItems offersItems, int position);
    }

    private final List<OffersItems> listSizes;
    private final OnStateClickListener onClickListener;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public RecyclerViewOfferSizeAdapter(Context context, List<OffersItems> listSizes, OnStateClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        this.listSizes = listSizes;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SizeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_catalog_element_inf_tp,
                parent, false);

        return new SizeViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void setListSizes(List<OffersItems> offersItems){
        listSizes.addAll(offersItems);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearItems(){
        listSizes.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SizeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        OffersItems offersItems = listSizes.get(position);

        holder.size.setText(offersItems.getSizeOffer());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            onClickListener.onStateClick(offersItems, position);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listSizes.size();
    }


    public static class SizeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private final TextView size;
        private final RelativeLayout relative;

        public SizeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            size = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSize);
            relative = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutSize);

        }
    }
}
```

Получившийся код не пропускает в switch

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
        if(!payloads.isEmpty()) {
            switch (payloads.get(0)) {
                case 1:
                    if (lastPosition >= 0){
                        notifyItemChanged(lastPosition, 2);
                    }
                    lastPosition = position;
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8DFFFFFF"));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }else {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
        }

        User user = users.get(position);
        holder.mTextUserName.setText(user.getName());
        holder.mTextUserAge.setText(user.getAge());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            onClickListener.onStateClick(user, position);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант использовать [notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)). Для этого в адаптере где у вас есть клик делаете вызов :

```
notifyItemChanged(position, 1);
```

и дальше в адаптере переопределяете метод:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
  if(!payloads.isEmpty()) {
                
  }else {
     super.onBindViewHolder(holder,position, payloads);
  }
}
```

внутри условия вы проверяете какой идентификатор у вашего изменения:

```
switch (payloads.get(0)) {
        case 1: 
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8DFFFFFF"));
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8DFFFFFF"));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

но вопрос в том как отловить выбор другого элемента отличного от уже выбранного. Для этого я бы предложил сохранять последнюю выбранную позицию и при клике ее обновлять:

```
public class RecyclerViewOfferSizeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewOfferSizeAdapter.SizeViewHolder>{
private Integer lastPosition = -1;
....

}
```

при клике вы будете менять фон:

```
notifyItemChanged(position, 1);
```

внутри условия с `case 1` проверяете:

```
case 1: 
    if (lastPosition >= 0){
       notifyItemChanged(lastPosition, 2);
    }
    lastPosition = position;
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8DFFFFFF"));
    break;
```

ну а в case 2 возвращаете нужный вам цвет. По логике должно работать нормально.

### UPDATE

Вот метод полностью:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {

        if (!payloads.isEmpty()) {
            switch ((Integer) payloads.get(0)) {
                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
                        if(i == position){
                            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#343434"));
                        }else{
                            int finalI = i;
                            Completable.complete()
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribe(() -> {
                                        notifyItemChanged(finalI,2);
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не получается сделать данную реализацию, во первых требует метод без payloads , во вторых в switch payloads.get(0) неверный тип данных.

Comment: переопределите тогда, я привел код выше, думал можно сразу скопировать, но может ошибка какая-то возникла

Comment: С переопределением разобрался, осталось понять что в свитче написать

Comment: вы пробовали код выше в ответе который?

Comment: у вас немного неправильно, либо я не понял что вы хотите по итогу получить, у вас будет два onBindViewHolder, в одном будет стартовое наполнение данными, а второй который я предложил будет отвечать за изменение дизайна

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10m3krw

Comment: С двумя холдерами получается так https://prnt.sc/10m3m2q

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120868/discussion-between-buenasdias-and-andrew).